# NiFi matching flowfiles based on some rules

Tags: graph, apache-nifi

I have two flowfiles from NiFi as follows:

```
Type:A
id:1

Type:B
id:1
```

I have some written rules that tell me Type A links to Type B if the id's match. So in the example above, it's a match!

Is there anyway i can use NiFi to compare flowfiles and figure out this connection? If not, what would be the best way to do this? What tools/technologies should i look into in order to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you described sounds like a streaming join which can be done with a stream processing system like Storm, Flink, Spark, etc.

NiFi focuses more on lookup joins where there is some kind of reference dataset, and something from incoming data is used to perform a look up into the reference dataset, and then enrich the incoming data.